# Find the total of prime numbers which have been multiplied without having knowledge of them

Tags: prime-factorization, python

Good day.

Suppose that $p$ is prime and that
$q$ is prime, and that

$$n = pq.$$

For example if $n = 21,$ then the corresponding "total" is  $10 = (3+7).$

Is it possible to get the total of the factors for $n$ without having information of the prime numbers ?

**important:** I had written a code to guess the factors, and i think it is possible to get the total, but it is important to find the total without bruteforcing or calculating by test and try on.

```
import math

n = p * q # ex: p=3 q=7

for i in range(1,n):
    s = math.sqrt(n + i**2)
    if s.is_integer() == True:
        print("sum =",s*2) # sum: 10 for i=2  3*7+2**2=25 => sqrt(25)=10//2
        break
```

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a closed function known for this, however, the function you are thinking of is called the $sopfr$ function. See https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SumofPrimeFactors.html for more information.

Comment: Well, as you had predicted, this might be the answer but i do not want to calculate the factors of n. It must be possible to calculate the sum of p and q, because there are only 3 and 7 which are in process.

Comment: @dude  if you know the sum of two numbers as well as their product, you can find the numbers explicitly. What the means: if you cannot factor the product, you cannot find the sum of the two primes

Comment: The code written above bruteforces the sum of factors without having knowledge of them. My problem is the following one: Yes, i can find out the sum of the factors of a number without factoring it, but it would take too long time if n grows to a larger number. What i need is a shorter way to calculate the sum.